# Android: PopupWindow animationStyle not working

Tags: android, android-animation, android-popupwindow

I have been stuck on this for a while now and went through other posts on this site but nothing works for me. I tried to create a basic dummy project and still no luck.

I am trying to use animations with popup window but my popup window doesn't show any animation while entering or disappearing. Am I missing something?

Below is the code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(window.decorView.rootView)
    }

    private fun onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(view: View?) {

        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        val inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val popupView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null)

        // create the popup window
        val width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val focusable = true // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable)

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        view?.doOnAttach {
            popupWindow.isFocusable = true
            popupWindow.animationStyle = R.style.Animation
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
        }

        Handler().postDelayed({
                                  popupWindow.dismiss()
                              }, 3000)
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*popup_window.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#62def8">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="This is a popup window."/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*themes.xml* *(both night and dark contain all values)*

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.PopupTest" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">@style/Animation</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Animation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_in_left</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.popuptest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PopupTest">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I never went back to verify this, but I ran into the same thing a bit ago on a previous question, and it seems like you have to use transitions instead for API level 24 and up: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-00WeA4FomhVK4cey0KtmxoNrDc1ML-7/view?usp=sharing. Btw, I don't see where you're applying your style anywhere. Did you make it the `android:popupAnimationStyle` in your theme?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot for the reply. My min sdk is set to 21. However I tried using transitions after raising the API level but no success.

However, I didn't know about the android:popupAnimationStyle attribute, which I have added now and made some edits to my code. However still no success. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you did have `R.style.Animation` in the code there. That might be a bit too late where it is, though. Also, it's not the minimum SDK that that depends on, but rather the Android version that you're running on currently. I'll see if I can spin up a test here after a bit.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok, I followed your comment and used transitions and it worked. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time. If you want you can add this as an answer and I would accept it. Or else I would post an update. Cheers!

Comment: Nice! Please feel free to post an answer yourself; I hadn't even refreshed my memory on the specific style setup yet. Glad I could suggest something useful. Thanks for the offer; I appreciate it. Cheers!